# Want to find transactions based on (credit amount > 100k) and debit amount ( >=90% of credit amount and <=105% of credit amount)

Tags: mysql

Want to find the transactions based on (credit amount > 100k) and debit amount ( >=90% of credit amount and <=105% of credit amount) have column to denote credit or debit on the particular date.

**i)** Transaction to fetch only if both credit and debit conditions satisfy
**ii)** In day we may have n credit and n debit, so need to sum the credit and debit based on the particular date, but in the output report transactions should not use sum function.

Table structure:

c1 - Amount
 
c2 - Credit or Debit
 
c3 - Customer
 
c4 - Date.

I just tried with first condition

`SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4 FROM cash FROM (c1 >=100k AND c2 = 'Credit')`

Comment: did you literally do 100k or did you put in 100,000?

Comment: transaction greater than 100000, hope its clarifies

Comment: If I am correct the above query can find transactions based on credit amount but not debit amount, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm not able to give both the condition. I tried many options but I'm not getting the output

Comment: are you using php, nodejs or something like that to perform queries?

Comment: Just I need this in MySQL script to validate the report

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be something like this:

`SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4 FROM cash WHERE (c1 >=100k AND c2 = 'Credit') OR (c1 >= [amount] AND c1 <= [amount] AND c2 = 'Debit')`

Comment: We should not use "or" condition as both credit and debit condition to satisfy,  and it's not "amount",  to find the transactions based on (credit amount > 100000) and debit amount ( >=90% of credit amount and <=105% of credit amount)

Comment: but i used a OR

Comment: I mean to say both credit and debit are mutually dependent, it cannot be separated,  i) Transaction to fetch only if both credit and debit conditions satisfy ii) In day we may have n credit and n debit, so need to sum the credit and debit based on the particular date, but in the output report transactions should not use sum function.

Comment: currently you only allow credit OR debit but not both so you need to change that in order to be able to achieve your goal